# Dependency Matrix for C# code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, matrix, dependencies

The dependency matrix of VS 2010 crashes VS 2010 as soon a I try it on my application! 
Anyone knows a good VS addin with a solid dependency matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool NDepend is integrated in VS 2012, 2010 and 2008 and comes with a [Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) that scales even on *very* large code base. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of this tool*

[image]

Also, this Dependency Matrix can interoperate with the NDepend's [Dependency Graph capabilities](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx):

[image]